# ITK: CannyEdgeDetectionFilter issues

Tags: c++, image-processing, itk

I'm trying to use the CannyEdgeDetectionImageFilter but the GetPixel() method doesn't seem to be properly referencing the filtered image. I've tried a lot of different tactics to attempt to resolve the issue, but the only thing that seems to work is writing and reading the image to/from the disk (which is not ideal). My code is below:

```
typedef itk::Image<unsigned char, 2>    ImageType;
typedef itk::Image<float, 2>        floatImageType;
```

...

```
floatImageType::Pointer to_float(ImageType::Pointer image){
    typedef itk::CastImageFilter <ImageType, floatImageType> CastFilterType;
    CastFilterType::Pointer castToFloat = CastFilterType::New();

    castToFloat->SetInput( image );
    castToFloat->Update();

    return castToFloat->GetOutput();
}
```

...

```
ImageType::Pointer check(ImageType::Pointer image){
    typedef itk::ImageDuplicator        <ImageType>     ImageDuplicatorType;
    typedef itk::RescaleIntensityImageFilter
                        <floatImageType, ImageType>     RescaleFilter;
    typedef itk::CannyEdgeDetectionImageFilter 
                    <floatImageType, floatImageType>    CannyFilter;

    RescaleFilter::Pointer          Rescale       = RescaleFilter::New();
    CannyFilter::Pointer            Canny         = CannyFilter::New();
    ImageDuplicatorType::Pointer    Duplicator    = ImageDuplicatorType::New();
    ImageType::Pointer              cannyImage;

    Canny->SetVariance( 20 );
    Canny->SetUpperThreshold(  2 );
    Canny->SetLowerThreshold( 20 );

    Rescale->SetOutputMinimum(    0 );
    Rescale->SetOutputMaximum(  255 );

    Duplicator->SetInputImage(image);
    Duplicator->Update();
    ImageType::Pointer img_copy = Duplicator->GetOutput();

    floatImageType::Pointer floatImage  = to_float(img_copy);

    Canny->SetInput(floatImage);
    Rescale->SetInput( Canny->GetOutput() );
    Rescale->Update();
    cannyImage = Rescale->GetOutput();

    /* Insert odd work-around here */

    const ImageType::SizeType img_size = cannyImage->GetLargestPossibleRegion().GetSize();

    itk::Index<2> loc = {{img_size[0]/2, 0}};
    int top_edge = 0;
    bool contin = true;

    for (int i = 0; ((i < img_size[1]) && contin); i++){
        loc[1] = i;

        if (cannyImage->GetPixel(loc) != 0){
            top_edge = i;
            contin = false;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

When a pixel value of `cannyImage` later on, the value should be either 0, or (if an edge) 255. However, it produces values that appear to belong to a gray-scale image.

However, if I include the following code in he section above, it works as one should expect:

```
    std::string fname = "/tmp/canny_" + to_string(getpid()) + ".tmp";
    writeImage(cannyImage, fname);
    cannyImage = readImage(fname);
```

(Methods `writeImage(ImageType::Pointer image, std::string filename)` and `ImageType::Pointer readImage(std::string filename)` were defined earlier the program.)

Anyone know what's going wrong with my program? Why does pushing it through the disk IO cause it to work?

Comment: When do you call getPixel? Are you using writeimage /readimage one after each like in the example, or you read the image just before calling getpixel? Maybe something is happening meanwhile (maybe somwhow cannyImage goes out of scope)

Comment: @lib I edited my post. Let me know if you you have any other questions.

Comment: mmm, I have no idea. One thing could be that the writer is forcing the pipeline to execute -I dont' see why it wouldn't be execute already, but you can tryto force it calling Modified() before Update(). I have also a doubt with the to_float method with the castfilter going out of scope, you can try to put it in the main code instead of calling it as a function (but actually if that was the problem also writeImage wouldn't work)

Comment: No luck with calling `Modified()` or with moving the `to_float()` components into the `check()` method.

The read / write cycle doesn't seem to have a significant impact on the computation time, but it doesn't make sense to me why that would resolve the issue... and that kinda bugs me.

Comment: While waiting somebody with a better idea, try to call ->GetOutput()->GetPixel(aFixedLoc) after each filter update, to see if you get some insight in what is going on

Comment: I tried doing `GetPixel()` at every stage I could think of and it seems that the CannyFilter just doesn't update . I did find, however, that writing and reading the image after putting it through the CannyFilter but before rescaling also solves the issue. Oh, well...
Thanks a ton for trying, though.

Comment: There is still the option of setting Canny->DebugOn to see what the filter is doing... sorry but I haven't tried to run and debug your code